# Problem with yad and variable's spaces its arguments

Tags: bash, shell-script, yad

My code works with:

```
binariesPathList="FALSE 'inkscape'
TRUE '/home/jeanfar/Downloads/binary-portable/inkscape/Inkscape-1.0-4035a4f-x86_64.AppImage'
FALSE '/home/jeanfar/Downloads/binary-portable/inkscape/Inkscape-f54ab5f-x86_64.AppImage'
FALSE '/home/jeanfar/git-clones/inkscape-0.92.5/build/install_dir/bin/inkscape'
FALSE '/home/jeanfar/git-clones/inkscape/build/install_dir/bin/inkscape'"

# This is to demonstrate how YAD will receive it. 
echo $binariesPathList

answer=$(yad \
    --list \
    --radiolist \
        --column="Pick" \
        --column="Application" \
        --column="Application Path" \
        $binariesPathList \
)
```

If you run that last code (Ignore buttons):
[image]

But fails with the exact same configuration, but three columns.
If you run it, you will note that even with the same `'` sign, it split by spaces.

```
binariesPathList="FALSE 'System Default Installation' 'inkscape'
TRUE '1.0 AppImage' '/home/jeanfar/Downloads/binary-portable/inkscape/Inkscape-1.0-4035a4f-x86_64.AppImage'
FALSE '1.1-dev Appimage' '/home/jeanfar/Downloads/binary-portable/inkscape/Inkscape-f54ab5f-x86_64.AppImage'
FALSE '0.92.5 Build' '/home/jeanfar/git-clones/inkscape-0.92.5/build/install_dir/bin/inkscape'
FALSE 'Master Build' '/home/jeanfar/git-clones/inkscape/build/install_dir/bin/inkscape'"

# This is to demonstrate how YAD will receive it. 
echo $binariesPathList

answer=$(yad \
    --list \
    --radiolist \
        --column="Pick" \
        --column="Application" \
        --column="Application Path" \
        $binariesPathList \
)
```

If you run that last code (Ignore buttons):
[image]

The really strange thing here is that you can put the parameters directly where the variable should be, and it will work even better than first, and even with those spaces.

It's exactly as a copy-paste of the echo, but if you replace the variable with `$(echo $binariesPathList)` it will be the same result.

```
answer=$(yad \
    --list \
    --radiolist \
        --column="Pick" \
        --column="Application" \
        --column="Application Path" \
        FALSE 'System Default Installation' 'inkscape' FALSE '1.0 AppImage' '/home/jeanfar/Downloads/binary-portable/inkscape/Inkscape-1.0-4035a4f-x86_64.AppImage' FALSE '1.1-dev Appimage' '/home/jeanfar/Downloads/binary-portable/inkscape/Inkscape-f54ab5f-x86_64.AppImage' FALSE '0.92.5 Build' '/home/jeanfar/git-clones/inkscape-0.92.5/build/install_dir/bin/inkscape' FALSE 'Master Build' '/home/jeanfar/git-clones/inkscape/build/install_dir/bin/inkscape' \
)
```

If you run that last code:
[image]

Comment: A workaround could be make the complete `yad` code a string and use `eval "...`, because then the `$binariesPathList` variable will be substituted before they passed to  `yad`. Just like copy-paste the `echo`. But this is not a really practical solution for every time I have this issue.

Comment: did you read those [comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/594058/how-to-store-and-print-variables-with-special-characters-in-shell-bash-sh#comment1108427_594058) and links [on your last post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/594058/170373) about the problems inherent in [storing commands in variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/170373)? Because that's what you're doing here, even if only for the actual command arguments and not for the command name.

Comment: Ok, your "post" looks very useful, but I always fall in the same issue (the use of `eval`), because the arguments I'm trying to passe are in a string that the user put trough a text input in yad. That input is converted to a variable, and that variable is what I need to use.

Comment: yes, then I suppose you'll need `eval` or something else that knows how to parse shell syntax

Comment: Another method is using the most complex system of regex to split that inputs in $@ then problem solved. But the code would be unreadable and also I know almost nothing (Zero) of regexs.

Comment: well, of course it also depends on if you want to support the full shell syntax, or just something simpler. And if you want to let the the user insert e.g. command substitutions or not. If it's the user themself entering code that eventually runs under their user account, there's no security issue

Comment: You could use xargs
`binariesPathList="$(printf "%s" "$binariesPathList" | xargs -n 1 printf "%s\n")"`
and then

`yad --list  --radiolist --column="Pick" --column="Application"        --column="Application Path"  <<<"${binariesPathList}"`